# How to tag certain records in a table based on terms within another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'd like to update this [Incoming] table with the appropriate TagName from the [TagNames] table. The [TagNames] table has a rank column that I have to respect. If the SearchTerm from the [TagSearchTerms] table is found anywhere in the title in the [Incoming] table then it is a match and it should be updated right then and there. If it matches on two or more terms, then the one with the lower numbered ranking wins (see that 5th record in the picture below with the two words underlined)

I have this done via a few handmade queries, but I really want to drive it better.

Here is what I have which works (you're not allowed to laugh at me :) )

```
  UPDATE Incoming SET TagName = 'Electrical' WHERE title LIKE '%electric%' AND TagName IS NULL OR TagName = '';
  UPDATE Incoming SET TagName = 'Electrical' WHERE title LIKE '%faceplate%' AND TagName IS NULL OR TagName = '';
  UPDATE Incoming SET TagName = 'Electrical' WHERE title LIKE '%wiring%' AND TagName IS NULL OR TagName = '';
  UPDATE Incoming SET TagName = 'Drywall' WHERE title LIKE '%drywall%' AND TagName IS NULL OR TagName = '';
  UPDATE Incoming SET TagName = 'Drywall' WHERE title LIKE '%sheetrock%' AND TagName IS NULL OR TagName = '';
```

As you can see, it walks down through the logic very awkwardly and makes sure not to tag something that already has a higher ranking value, naturally. That code actually works. However, I need to do this on a much bigger scale which would make this into hundreds of lines/tags so it needs to be more usable.

I've assumed that I will need to table drive this so I have created these other tables. Any of this can be redesigned if need be as I have the ability to do that within this database.

Can anyone give me some advice on how to achieve this using a JOIN or maybe even a loop with some reusability? I would be most grateful.

(Below is the layout and data examples of what I have now and below the green arrows is what I want to get to)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the tags in a single query:

```
UPDATE Incoming
    SET TagName = (CASE WHEN title LIKE '%electric%' OR  
                             title LIKE '%faceplate%' OR
                             title LIKE '%wiring%' 
                        THEN 'Electrical' 
                        WHEN title LIKE '%drywall%' 
                             title LIKE '%sheetrock%' 
                        THEN 'Drywall'
                   END);
```

With your table structure, you could do something like:

```
UPDATE incoming
    SET TagName = (SELECT TOP 1 tst.TagName
                   FROM TagSearchTerms tst JOIN
                        TagName tn
                        ON tst.tagname = tn.tagname
                   WHERE incoming.title like '%' + tst.searchterm + '%'
                   ORDER BY tn.rank
                  );
```

Comment: This is great, Gordon! It didn't allow me to alias the "incoming i" table, but this totally just worked! Thank you so much, man. I am studying this code as we speak to learn more from it.

Comment: Hey @Gordon-Linoff . I was wondering if you might help with a followup question with this query? How might I amend it to also update the [TagSearchTerms] table? I want to add a LastMatchedTime column to that table and set it to the GETDATE() if it is a match for that term. That way I can tell when the last time that one of the SearchTerms was actually utilized because I might want to retire them one day if they aren't being used any longer. I was wondering if there was a slick way to do this within that subquery already so that it isn't doubling the work or anything?

Comment: @FujiBob . . . I think you should ask another question, along with sample data and desired results.